# while adding events to Fullcalendar by external drag and drop, item doesn't get id

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar's external drag and drop, with his code. http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/external-dragging.html

```
drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
```

Every thing is okay, but I want to add this dropped event to my database. So I added my add dialog codes here.

```
var eventToAdd = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()),
                //title: $(this).attr('id'),
                description: $(this).attr('original-title'),
                start: date.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                end: date.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

        };

        if (checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.title) || checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.description)) {
            alert("please enter characters: A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, spaces");
        }
        else {
            //alert("sending " + eventToAdd.title);

            PageMethods.addEvent(eventToAdd, addSuccess);
        }
```

So the result is,

```
drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                if($(this).attr('id')=='')
                    return;
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            $(this).remove();


            var eventToAdd = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()),
                //title: $(this).attr('id'),
                description: $(this).attr('original-title'),
                start: date.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                end: date.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

            };

            if (checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.title) || checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.description)) {
                alert("please enter characters: A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, spaces");
            }
            else {
                //alert("sending " + eventToAdd.title);

                PageMethods.addEvent(eventToAdd, addSuccess);
            }
        }
```

Event is shown, event is draggable, but it doesn't get the Id. I think the event which rendered at this row isn't related with the event sent to the database:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem, not when dropping an external element, but when creating a new event by clicking on a time slot.

If you require the id, you must not render directly the event dropped, but obtain its data (title, start, end, allday), save it to the database, retrieve the saved event and render it. This way it will have the ID associated to it.

The method used to save it to the database, must return the event information required by fullcalendar to be rendered.

This is the code I have used:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {

//code required to initialise the variables used in the ajax call
//...

    //URL used to call my cakephp controller/action along with the data required to save the event to the database
    var url = "/eugdef/availabilities/add?start="+startyear+"-"+startmonth+"-"+startday+" "+starthour+":"+startminute+":00&end="+endyear+"-"+endmonth+"-"+endday+" "+endhour+":"+endminute+":00&allday="+allday+"&teacher_id="+teacher_id+"&teacher_name="+teacher_name+"&semester="+semester+"&year_id="+year_id;
    $.post(
        url, 
        function(data){ //callback function retrieving the response sent by the controller/action
            //event is the object that will actually be rendered to the calendar
            var event = jQuery.parseJSON(data.substr(1,data.length-2));
            //actually rendering the new event to the calendar
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, false);
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }
    );
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yeah it helps, I got it. Thanks Stepanek.

Answer (score 4):

FYI you can also set an id for the draggable div in your HTML, then do something like:

```
copiedEventObject.id = $( this ).attr('id');
```

inside the "drop:" attribute (right after:

```
var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
```

in the "external-dragging.html" example.

Comment: Awesome, That works! Thanks!
Actually I am handling events to hide and show , when external events drop on calendar, or remove from calendar.

Answer (score 0):

For external events, the `drop` callback is only for the "low-level" dropping data. The `eventReceive` callback is what you want:

```
eventReceive: function(event, view) {
                alert("Dropped event: " + event['title']);  // any data linked to the dropped event 
            },
```

Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/